# How Monaco Editor completion items provider can wait for async suggestions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, monaco-editor

Goal: **Wait custom suggestions from a fake server response.**

Problem: I cannot understand how I can tell to Monaco editor completion items provider *to wait for async suggestions.*

Playground example:

1. [Go to playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example)
2. Paste the following code

```js
console.log("1. Instantiate a standalone code editor");

const language = "json"
const content = `{\n\t\"dependencies\": {\n\t\t\n\t}\n}\n`
const options = {
  value: content,
  language: language,
  tabSize: 2
}
const standaloneCodeEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), options);
const sce = standaloneCodeEditor;

console.log("2. Declare function to provide a completion items")

function provideCompletionItems(model, position) {
  console.log("Invoking function 'provideCompletionItems'")

  var textUntilPosition = model.getValueInRange({ startLineNumber: 1, startColumn: 1, endLineNumber: position.lineNumber, endColumn: position.column });
  console.log("textUntilPosition:", textUntilPosition)
    
  var match = textUntilPosition.match(/"dependencies"\s*:\s*\{\s*("[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"\s*,\s*)*([^"]*)?$/);
  console.log("match:", match)

  if (!match) {
  return { suggestions: [] };
  }

  var word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
  console.log("word:", word)

  var range = {
    startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
    endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
    startColumn: word.startColumn,
    endColumn: word.endColumn
  };
  console.log("range:", range)

  const mock_serverResponse = [
    {
      label: '"lodash"',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
      documentation: "The Lodash library exported as Node.js modules.",
      insertText: '"lodash": "*"',
      range: range
    },
    {
      label: '"lodash111"',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
      documentation: "The Lodash111 library exported as Node.js modules.",
      insertText: '"lodash111": "*"',
      range: range
    },
    {
      label: '"express"',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
      documentation: "Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework",
      insertText: '"express": "*"',
      range: range
    },
    {
      label: '"mkdirp"',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
      documentation: "Recursively mkdir, like <code>mkdir -p</code>",
      insertText: '"mkdirp": "*"',
      range: range
    },
    {
      label: '"my-third-party-library"',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
      documentation: "Describe your library here",
      insertText: '"${1:my-third-party-library}": "${2:1.2.3}"',
      insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
      range: range
    }
  ]

  let myCustomSuggestions = [];
  console.log("myCustomSuggestions:",myCustomSuggestions)

  setTimeout(() => {
    const myPromise = Promise.resolve(mock_serverResponse)
    console.log("myPromise:",myPromise)

    myPromise
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response:", response)
      
        response.forEach(e => myCustomSuggestions.push(e))
        console.log("myCustomSuggestions:",myCustomSuggestions)

        return {
          suggestions: myCustomSuggestions
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err)) 
  }, 2000)
  
}

console.log("3. Register completion items provider")
const completionItemProvider = monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(language, {
    provideCompletionItems: () => provideCompletionItems(sce.getModel(), sce.getPosition())
});
```

3. Display web developer console (to see log messages)
4. Run the program
5. Type into brackets the word lodash
6. See web developer console
7. Notice that no suggestions are displayed

Comment: Why would you want to wait for the suggestions? It would block your UI. Instead the approach to return the suggestions using a promise is the right way. If that takes longer Monaco will show a "Loading..." popup.

Comment: I want to wait the suggestions because in the real app, not this simple example, suggestions are given from a server... frontend take a string and call an API endpoint - server returns a list of suggestions and user can use it to complete the editing in editor.

Comment: I'd like to see that 'Loading...' on monaco editor suggestion panel - can you modify my simple example to show me how can I get it?

Comment: Tricky to do in a comment. Try yourself, change the `provideCompletionItems` function. Remove the existing return call and return instead: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {});` Then run the example and trigger code completion with ctrl+space. You will see the "Loading..." popup, because the promise is never resolved.

Answer (score 1):

provideCompletionItems method support a `Promise` return result. [monaco.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/website/typedoc/monaco.d.ts#L6246)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#### it's easy to solve this problem.

##### first of all, don't show anything when need competion, or show something you like.And you need to know how to show suggestions actively. yes use this code:

```js
isReady=true;
yourEditor.trigger('anything', 'editor.action.triggerSuggest', {});
```

now we can show suggestion in any time.

#### Now we get it!

```js
let yourSuggestions = [];
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('vb', {
    provideCompletionItems: function (model, position) {
        // show some waitting message here
        if(isReady){
            return {suggestion: yourSuggestions}
        }
        requestSuggestions();
        return {suggestions:[]};
    }
});

function requestSuggestions(){
    // do something you need
    $.ajax({
        //.....
        success(data){
            isReady = true;
            yourSuggestions = data.suggestions;
            yourEditor.trigger('anything', 'editor.action.triggerSuggest', {});
        }
    })
}
```

##### this just a method and you can prove it